# $\int_{-1}^1 (t-1)\left(e^\frac{1}{\Gamma(t)}-1\right)dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am looking for a way to evaluate the integral

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\left(t - 1\right)\left[\mathrm{e}^{1/\Gamma\left(t\right)} - 1\right]\mathrm{d}t
$$

This integral appears to almost have a sort of symmetry about the $y$-axis that could yield a cancellation, but I have been unable to show this. Numerical integration yields a value of $−0.0001194628623602256$. I am curious if there is a way to evaluate this integral, perhaps exploiting any potential symmetry, but I would not be surprised if there is no such method given the difficulty in working with the gamma function.

I have tried substituting $t=-u$ and breaking up the integral into two parts in order to solve but have so far been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this kind of small numbers using the Taylor expansion of $e^\frac{1}{\Gamma(t)}$ built at $t=0$ and integrate termwise. This would be quite long; the first terms are
$$e^\frac{1}{\Gamma(t)}-1=t+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\gamma \right) t^2+\left(\frac{1}{6}+\gamma +\frac{\gamma
   ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right) t^3+$$ $$\frac{1}{24}  \left(1+12 \gamma +24
   \gamma ^2+4 \gamma ^3-2 \pi ^2-2 \gamma  \pi ^2-4 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$

Let us admit that you are sufficiently patient to do the expansion up to $O\left(t^{p+1}\right)$. You should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{result} \\
 2 & -0.05147711 \\
 4 & +0.06413149 \\
 6 & -0.00956415 \\
 8 & -0.00483854 \\
10 & +0.00118575 \\
12 & -0.00041961 \\
14 & -0.00003656
\end{array}
\right)$$ I  give up (my computer too !).